# Web page becomes inactive while waiting for AJAX response?

Tags: javascript, ajax, response, html

I have used a simple AJAX call in a webpage.
he webpage is like this. On clicking the submit button the JavaScript sends the data in a text box to server and displays the response in a div.

My AJAX code is:

```
var xmlHttp = null;
var api="getdetails.jsp?id=";
var theUrl=api.concat(theId);
xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
xmlHttp.send();
document.getElementById("details").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
```

But the problem is that while waiting for the AJAX response the webpage becomes inactive. That is, the user cannot type in text box or click any other link or so. Nothing can be done till the response is received.

**How can I make the webpage to be functional while waiting for the response**? Do I have to employ multi-threading or any other way?

Comment: Please post your JavaScript code

Comment: Apparently your AJAX call is synchronous (which is **not** the default behaviour). Show us your AJAX request code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your ajax request asynchronous, by setting the

```
xmlhttp.open("GET",theUrl,true);
```

third parameter in your request as true.

Also this line

```
document.getElementById("details").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
```

Should be written with

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange
```

so that when a state change happens and the result is available in responseText then only u can set a dom element. Please read the documentation of using ajax carefully.

See this example http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first

Comment: But changing it seems to affect the request it seems. The web page reloads instead of showing the response. Do i need to change anything in addition to this?

Comment: You also need to use `xmlHttp.onreadystatechange` to show the data when received...[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)